# Trying to Understand fgets()

Tags: c, fgets, file-read

I'm writing a program to read a file line by line. I know fgets() will read up until a new line, n-1 characters, or EOF. What confuses me is how does fgets() know to advance to a new line/where it is in a file?

To be clearer, I know in Java you have to explicitly tell the scanner to read the next line. But in C, I just put fgets() in a while loop and trust that is does it's job.

How can I logically reassure myself that fgets() is actually advancing to the next line, and not reading the same line over and over again in that while loop (yes, I know I can print things out)?

Comment: Given that fgets() takes a file pointer, it will just advance that pointer through the file, just past the next newline. If you would use any reading functionality on that file (not just fgets), these would start where fgets() left the file pointer: right after the newline.

Comment: That's what it is required to do. I don't know why (or even whether) Java does as you claim, but for C's `fgets()` to do the same would break every C program that uses it.

Comment: "not reading the same line over and over again in that while loop": in a sense, you can't. You just trust the people who implemented the library function. So if, somehow, somewhere, you got an April-1st style library, your scenario could happen (and functionality such as ftell would then similarly be botched). But it's certainly not supposed to.

Comment: @Everet Ah, I think I'm beginning to understand. So if I wanted to restart from the beginning of the file, I would have fclose(myFilePtr), then run the loop again?

Comment: Closing and opening the file is one way to restart, yes. Probably easier (tiny bit quicker as well) is to use `rewind` or `fseek`. Have a read through the man pages for fgets, rewind, fseek etc. Or see if you can find a reasonably detailed guide on file/stream access in C. [The C IO chapter of Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/File_IO) may be a good start.

Comment: Generally, try to think of a file as a continuous series of bytes that you move along, reading them along the way. If your file is short, you could draw the various actions on a piece of paper and see how things move, including fgets.

Comment: There's one thing to note about fgets: if the size parameter is shorter than the line, fgets will read up to that point. The next iteration, it will continue *from that point*. It will not skip the rest of the line and start at the next line. So if you want to read full lines, always make sure that the size parameter (and the input buffer) are as long as the longest line you want to read (including the newline).

Comment: The code knows where the end of a line is by reading bytes from the file until one of those bytes is the newline character (`'\n'`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The semantics of `fgets()` are quite straight forward: read bytes from the `FILE*` stream pointer until either:

- the destination array is full (`n-1` bytes have been read and stored into it).
- a newline was read from the stream and stored into the destination array.
- the end of file has been reached or a read error occurred (`EOF` was returned by the `fgetc()` call or equivalent). end-of-file and read-error conditions can be distinguished by calling `ferr()` and/or `feof()` after `fgets()` returns `NULL`.

A null terminator is always stored into the array after the bytes read from the stream, unless end of file was reached immediately (`fgets()` returns `NULL`) or if the buffer size is specified as having a size of 0.

`fgets()` behaves as if the stream was read one byte at a time with `fgetc()`.

`fgets()` consumes the bytes read from the stream and stores them into the destination array. It cannot read the same bytes again unless you explicitly seek backwards into the stream with `rewind()`, `fseek()` or `fsetpos()`, if the stream supports seeking at all. Streams attached to regular files usually support seeking, but files open in text mode require specific handling on some systems, notably Microsoft Windows. Note also that a byte pushed back into the stream with `ungetc()` will be read by `fgets()` before any bytes from the actual stream.

`fgets()` stores the newline character into the destination array if the line was short enough to fit in the array before the null terminator.

`fgets()` breaks long lines into smaller chunks if the line exceeds the available space in the destination array. Handling long lines is tricky and error prone. Note that when `fgets()` reads a partial line due to lack of space in the destination array, the next call to `fgets()` will continue reading from the same line at the point where the previous call stopped.

If upon return from `fgets()`, the destination array does not end with a newline, one of the following occurred:

- the current line was too long and only as many bytes as fit in the array were read from the stream.
- the line read was the last in the file and the file does not end with a newline sequence.
- a null byte was read from the file.

Mishandling these cases may result in potential undefined behavior and/or exploitable flaws.

Comment: Are only regular files seekable? Or, more to the point, does the Standard specify any guarantees about when a file should support positioning requests?

Comment: Nice answer.  Notes: `fgets()` can re-read the last character with an `ungetc()`.  This answer omits discussion about rare input errors - which is not necessary for an initial `fgets()` understanding - other than to know it exists.

Comment: @david_bowling: no guarantees whatsoever.

Comment: @chux: I also kept from the casual reader the gory details of potential problems with wide-oriented streams hitting encoding errors... for good reason.

Comment: This had all I needed to know about fgets(). Thanks!